# SQL Server DateTime Query Issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-ce

I am using SqlServer Compact 3.5 (2008) and am trying to return rows that have a datetime field that is today or previous. This is the code I am trying, but it is throwing an exception. (in the Where clause)

I'm new to SQL so I'm having trouble with this one. Any ideas? If you need more data, let me know.

```
string selectStatement = 
  "SELECT * FROM EnglishSpanish ORDER BY AvgScore DESC " +
  "WHERE NextShow <= @Today";
SqlCeCommand selectCommand = new SqlCeCommand(selectStatement, connection);
selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Today", DateTime.Today);
```

Comment: The specific exception you're receiving would be useful to diagnose this =)

Comment: That said, I think both answers that are regarding query order (i.e. WHERE needs to be before ORDER BY) are the correct answer to your problem =)

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me solve this so quickly. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "ORDER BY" clause must come after the "WHERE" clause.  The SQL statement should read

```
SELECT * FROM EnglishSpanish 
WHERE NextShow < @Today
ORDER BY AvgScore DESC
```

Also notice that I am using "<" instead of "<=". Instead of using `DateTime.Today` you should use `DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)` because `DateTime.Today` will give you '2010-07-29 00:00:00' which is midnight between July 28th and 29th. Hence your clause will not give you the records of today.

Comment: Thank you for the extra info. In my case, I only write things using DateTime.Today and additions to that, so all of my SQL Dates should be on the midnight time, but I'll definitely look at my data and make sure it is behaving as expected.

Answer (score 3):

The correct Sql Syntax would be

```
SELECT * FROM EnglishSpanish 
WHERE NextShow <= @Today
ORDER BY AvgScor DESC
```

Your `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses are reversed.

Also.  Don't `SELECT *`.  Even if you're selecting all of them, name your columns.

Answer (score 2):

In lieu of the specific exception you're retrieving, try changing your query so that it's structured like this:

```
SELECT * FROM EnglishSpanish WHERE NextShow <= @Today ORDER BY AvgScore DESC
```

I *think* the `WHERE` clause has to come before the `ORDER BY` clause

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a parameter for this query, unless you want to support the possibility of change in the future - you can use `GETDATE()` to return the current datetime:

```
    SELECT * 
      FROM EnglishSpanish
  WHERE nextshow <= GETDATE() 
ORDER BY AvgScore DESC
```

The problem was that you had the `WHERE` clause in the wrong spot - it's after the FROM, before the GROUP BY, HAVING, ORDER BY (in that order).